# YARD convention for truthiness

Tags: ruby, yard, truthiness

Is there a convention to indicate that a parameter in YARD style documentation is only used for its "truthiness" status, that is you only want to know if it's `false` or `nil` or is truthy?

What is typically put in place of `Truthy` in the following?

```
# @param [String] name
# @param [Truthy] admin_status 
def create_user(name, admin_status)
  # code goes here
end
```

The closest I can find in the [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/docs/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#Class_or_Module_Types) is Boolean, which isn't really what I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using anything other than Boolean would imply that you're doing some sort of special handling, like interpreting `0` as *false* or something less literal than true/false checking.

You can see the convention used in the [YARD docs](http://rubydoc.info/docs/yard/YARD/CLI/Yardoc) where `Boolean` represents both the `TrueClass` and `FalseClass` types. This type does not
exist in Ruby, however.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a convention to indicate that a parameter in YARD style documentation is only used for its "truthiness" status

No. Below might be a workaround that's pretty close to what you requested:

```ruby
# @param [Object] admin_status only used for its "truthiness" status
```

or

```ruby
# @param [Object] admin_status check if it is false/nil/truthy
```

In other words, rely on param comment and accept anything as a type(therefore `Object`).